# Notification Extension

Tags: android, notifications, sony, sony-smartwatch

I have just started to create notification for my extension. The first thing I do is try to see from sample notification extension. As I run it, I saw in events is like this:

http://s14.postimg.org/yzh8z78ht/SC20131014_084520.jpg

I saw from Sony documentation (smart emulator overview), it should be like this:
http://s11.postimg.org/imwn7cw9f/event.png

I don't know what I suppose to see from the sample notification. Anybody know how the sample works? 
In documentation, it said that:

> A notification Smart Extension app is an Android application which
>   communicates with Smart Connect and inserts events in its notification
>   content provider to be displayed on compatible accessories.

From that statement, do I have to build another application for showing the notification from my application? Right now I have phone application that can send the information (in String) from  smartphone to extension. I want to show notification when the value is received. So,do I have to make separate application? Or just add some method to build the notification inside my current extension?Anybody knows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it seems you are working with the old Smart Extension SDK - you should upgrade to the [Sony Add-on SDK v2](http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/sony-add-on-sdk/) to get the newest APIs for the newest Sony Mobile accessories, and the updated emulator.

Regarding your question(s) - the way the notification API basically works, you add notifications to the Smart Connect notification database via a Content Provider. Once the notification has been added, all connected Sony Smart accessories will display the notification. To add this functionality to your application, you can go about it in two ways:

1. Add the extension functionality to your already existing app. By doing this, you will not need to send the String (that you mention) between app processes.
2. Create a separate notification extension which takes the information from your app.

For both implementations, you can use the SampleNotificationExtension project that is included in the SDK to start your work from.

Hope this helps, cheers!

Comment: Hi Jerker, Is it mandatory for me to update my SmartExtension SDK?Is it the new SDK has the new verion for sampleNotificationExtension?Or it also the same as the current version in version 1.1?

Comment: For the notification API, it is not mandatory to update - you can continue working on your current version. But we recommend to update, to get the full functionality :)

Comment: Hi Jerker, Thank you for your information. I can make notification based on SampleNotificationExtension which I found in the new Sony sdk version. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Please check this and let me know if you can help me out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020613/send-notifications-to-sony-smartwch-2/21020794?noredirect=1#21020794